# How do I resize a UIButton to fit the text without it going wider than the screen?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have a UIButton that I want to resize to fit whatever text is inside it.  It has a set width of 280, but the text should wrap to the next line(s) and extend the height of the button as needed.

I've set line breaks to Word Wrap and tried sizeToFit but that only makes the button go wider, not vertical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get it working in a category of UIButton:

```
@interface UIButton (ExpandsVertically)

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size;

@end

@implementation UIButton (Expandable)

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {

    // for the width, I subtract 24 for the border
    // for the height, I use a large value that will be reduced when the size is returned from sizeWithFont
    CGSize tempSize = CGSizeMake(size.width - 24, 1000);

    CGSize stringSize = [self.titleLabel.text
                         sizeWithFont:self.titleLabel.font
                         constrainedToSize:tempSize
                         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return CGSizeMake(size.width - 24, stringSize.height);
}

@end
```

If anyone uses this make sure to set:

```
myButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

Answer (score 36):

Make sure you set the text on your button this way:

```
[myButton setTitle:@"my title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

... and `[myButton sizeToFit]` should work like a charm.

Comment: I think this may not work properly on buttons with type=custom

Answer (score 8):

`[button sizeToFit]` didn't work for me, but I've found a way using IB alone (xcode 4.5):

1. Click on the `UIButton`
2. in the Size inspector drag `content hugging` to 1 (both horizontal and vertical)
3. drag `compression resistance` to 1000 (for both)
4. under the UIButton's `constraints` click on `Width` and change `priority` to 250
5. Do the same for Height
6. You can use the `UIButton`'s `inset` to control padding for left/right/top/bottom

Comment: Did you try using inset? If I use inset it seems autolayout does not take into account while calculating the expected width so even though button width grows but its not sufficient to accommodate text+left right inset

Comment: using Content insets instead of Title insets worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at the [*UIKit Additions to NSString* documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) which includes methods for font measurement constrained to a specific width or box size.

When you set the button's title, you could measure the string using the *sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:* method, for example, and update your button's frame based on the size returned (possibly allowing for some padding around the edges).

Sorry I don't have a specific example for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing a similar problem, had limited width for my buttons and wanted them to grow vertically, depending on the amount of text I'd give them.
I ended up with a simple solution, based on what I've learnt in the Apple docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ImplementingView/ImplementingView.html)

I've subclassed `UIButton` and overridden two functions:

```
- (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    if (!CGRectEqualToRect(bounds, self.bounds)) {
        [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    }
    [super setBounds:bounds];
}

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    //
    CGSize size;

    self.titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.titleLabel.frame.origin.x,
            self.titleLabel.frame.origin.y,
            self.frame.size.width - self.contentEdgeInsets.left - self.contentEdgeInsets.right - self.titleEdgeInsets.left - self.titleEdgeInsets.right,
            0);
    size = [self.titleLabel sizeThatFits:self.titleLabel.frame.size];
    size = CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height + 20);

    return size;
}
```

What basically happens here is that the button invalidates its intrinsic size (only when the bounds set are actually new -- this is to prevent an endless loop), and when the system asks for the intrinsic content size, I recalculate that based on the width of the button. The extra 20px height is for padding.
I've tried many other ways but since my layout is all based on AutoLayout, I wanted something that I don't have to update whenever the device rotates or so. This simply works.

Good luck!
Z.