# Why is my app missing the UIImagePickerController cancel/preview/choose toolbar?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, camera

My app is not doing anything special with the UIImagePickerController. I'm allowing the user to pick from the camera if available or to pick from the photo albums otherwise.

I notice that there's no retake/use screen when using the camera, and there's no cancel/Preview/choose toolbar when picking.

I don't see how this is enabled in the documentation.  There's nothing...

Was this an old feature that's now been removed in 4.2+?  I notice the Messages app and WhatsApp both have these preview toolbars.

What am I missing?  Thanks!

Here's an example project I whipped up.  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4153528/PickerTest.zip

It shows the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you haven't applied the UIButton (ExpandsVertically) category:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4978003/2005332

It can cause the buttons of the UIImagePickerController to disappear