# How to resize a custom Button in iphone according to it Text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have implemented a custom button as follows.

```
UIButton *mainBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[mainBtn setTitle:@"Meeting" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[mainBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 7, 72, 35)];
[mainBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonActive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
mainBtn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 5, 18, 10);
[mainBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Here button title going to be dynamic one. So now I need to change the button width according to the length of the title dynamicaly. For that CGRectMake with given width wont work. Can some one help me to do that.

Comment: This should do the trick...

http://stackoverflow.com/a/4978003/716216

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the following code,

```
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [mainBtn.titleLabel.text sizeWithFont:mainBtn.titleLabel.font]; 
mainBtn.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, expectedLabelSize.width+10, expectedLabelSize.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpel solution would be [mainBtn sizeToFit];
But I don't know whether this takes your edgeInsets into account.