# Possible to get UIButton sizeThatFits to work?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit

I have been using a method of resizing my UIButtons that is depreciated, and not very robust.  For that and also other reasons, I want to get sizeThatFits to work for UIButtons.  From what I've read online, I'm not sure if it should work (seems like it is working for some, but not others, the difference maybe between the style, I'm using custom).

Here is my simple test code to recreate the issue (I just put this in viewDidLoad to test, but shouldn't matter, and my real code is part of a large project):

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setTitle:@"This is a test with a long title that will need to word wrap to more than a single line when displayed on my tiny iPod in portrait view." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap; // depreciated - but nothing to replace it?
CGRect r = btn.frame;
r.origin.x = 0;
r.origin.y = 0;
r.size.width = 320;
r.size.height = [btn.titleLabel.text sizeWithFont:btn.titleLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(r.size.width,100000) lineBreakMode:btn.titleLabel.lineBreakMode].height; // Returns approx 86 and changes correctly if I change the title text
r.size.height = [btn sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(r.size.width,CGFLOAT_MAX)].height; // returns 34 no matter what
btn.frame = r;
```

The sizeWithFont line is what I have been doing, and it works, but it isn't asking the actual control for the size, so not really safe and has been depreciated also.  The sizeThatFits line is what I would like to get working, but it always returns 34 no matter what (probably the recommended/default height of a button).

I've been using the same sizeWithFont to resize UILabels and some other controls as well.  I've updated them to use sizeThatFits and they work great, just UIButton isn't working the same as the others.  **I'm hoping there is a simple fix, like setting a property of the UIButton, to get this working?**

My app only needs to support iOS 8+, not older versions.

Update: Based on the comments here [How do I resize a UIButton to fit the text without it going wider than the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960377/how-do-i-resize-a-uibutton-to-fit-the-text-without-it-going-wider-than-the-scree) and the accepted answer, it seems like we might be stuck with sizeWithFont or other sub-par solutions... dang.

Comment: Isn't it `.sizeToFit` instead `.sizeThatFits`?

Comment: Both are valid functions.  I lean towards sizeThatFits because it is more obvious how it will/should work since you pass in a CGSize, unlike sizeToFit which I assume uses constraints/auto-layout rules.

Comment: ok but did you try `.sizeToFit`?

Comment: Good point, and I just tried it.  It works for UILabel but for UIButton it is making the button super wide.. increasing the width, not the height.  That gives me some clues though, maybe a matter of needing to set some constraints.

Comment: When I searched SO on sizeToFit I got a lot more hits than sizeThatFits, so thank you for pointing me in that direction.  I tried some different constraints/autoresizingMask and so far no luck.  Based on the new info I've been reading, it sounds like I might just be stuck with some "hacks" for now.

Comment: Have you tried setting the number of lines to `btn.titleLabel` as well as your line breaking (which should be `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`)? You probably need to set `btn.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0` to get unlimited lines. The default value is 1, which I think is what you're running into. I'd add that and then try `sizeToFit` again while already having the max width you want set. Or `sizeThatFits` may work as well, as long as you pass the largest width you want.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it using UIButton titleLabel instead of UIButton.

```
button.titleLabel?.sizeThatFits(labelFitSize)
```

Instead of

```
button.sizeThatFits(labelFitSize)
```

Good news is that it works, bad news you will need to handle yourself if the button as contentInsets or images...