# UIButton width or line break mode problem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm programmatically adding `UIButton` objects to an `UIScrollView`. The result I'm getting is that the height of the button is calculated properly, i.e. there is a space for a second line, but the text does not wrap, it rather continues to flow as if the button has infinite width. I used to have `UITextView` objects instead of the buttons, and that worked flawlessly. I just cannot set the buttons to layout the same way the text views did.

Here's a code snipplet:

```
UIButton* sButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yPos, sWidth - 5, height)];
sText = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"quite a long string that does not fit in one line, no chance"];
sButton.titleLabel.font = font;
sButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[sButton setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[sButton.titleLabel setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[sButton setTitle:sText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sButton sizeToFit];
```

And this is the result I'm getting: [image]

How can I make the button text wrap?

Comment: If you want text to wrap - whether in a text view, label, or the title label of a button - you must give it a width restriction.

Comment: If you are targeting iOS 15+, you can create multiline-title buttons easily with `UIButtonConfiguration`

Comment: @DonMag thanks for the input! I'm constructing the `UIButton` with a frame, why is that ignored after the call to `sizeToFit`?

Comment: You're constructing the button with a frame... then you're calling `sizeToFit` --- *"Call this method when you want to resize the current view"*. So, you are setting the frame after setting the frame. You really want to be using auto-layout with a width constraint.

Comment: @DonMag I didn't need to call `sizeToFit` when I had `UITextView` objects instead of `UIButton`s. Without the call to `sizeToFit` the view is all messed up for some reason. Anyway, the `sizeToFit` keeps the correct height of the button, as you can see on the image I posted, but the fails to word wrap the contents, or to observe the width size set at construction time. Why does it observe some values, while ignoring others, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only solution I've found that works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4978003/963022

I ended up creating a custom button implementation and overriding:

```
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {

    int diff = 0;
    // for the width, subtract DIFF for the border
    // for the height, use a large value that will be reduced when the size is returned from sizeWithFont
    CGSize tempSize = CGSizeMake(size.width - diff, 1000);

    CGSize stringSize = [self.titleLabel.text
                     sizeWithFont:self.titleLabel.font
                     constrainedToSize:tempSize
                     lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return CGSizeMake(size.width - diff, stringSize.height);
}
```